# Consistent approach to securing data on IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, security

I am pondering a solution for a healthcare application that involves a cloud based service used by healthcare providers.

The solution will store personal (medical) information about patients. It is a white labeled solution to be used by different health care companies. I have a reasonable handle on the server side security but the app side (and to an extent the transmission of data between app and server) is my main concern for the moment.

I am looking for an approach that is as "common as possible" between IOS and Android (is this possible at all) but will meet the following criteria:

- Secure the data so that it can only be retrieved via an "unreasonable" amount of effort (I know I am being wooly).
- Ensure that it is not (reasonably) possible for Health Care Provider (HCP-A) to recover data that belonged to HCP-B simply by having the same application and (somehow) a copy of the data that belonged to HCP-A. I think the answer to this is to have the users application password as part of the encryption algorithm?
- Handles both "normal" sql type data (or possibly XML) and binary data (specifically photographs).

I realise this may be a very "101" question - is there a definitive reference that will help me get up to speed with the concepts?

Comment: You need to provide more details, what and where do you want to secure? Most importantly, can your client app retrieve and use securely stored information or not?

Comment: I want a data store (SQL or XML). Data is patient data. I want to secure the patient data and binary images (photos). Client app will be built to retrieve and use the secured information. So I am trying to think this from the bottom up - I want to get a secure store on the device first and then build the app around that.

Comment: Sorry to disapoint you but there is no way you can achieve needed security level on a plain android device, you will need additional hardware support for that kind of things.

Comment: Okas, thanks for the response. From this can I conclude that I can acheive this in IOS (and therefore IOS security is better than Android?)

Comment: No, not exactly. Just I dont know ios too well. I'm sure that on a rooted ios device things are just the same.

Comment: If you are going to have patient data and are in the U.S. you will need to comply with HIPPA.

Comment: If you encrypt the data and key the key in the Keychain and the usr has a good (more than 4 digit PIN) even rooted iOS devices are as secure a the lock code.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the data stored locally with a strong symmetric encryption algorithm like AES, decrypt on fly using a criteria at your choice and use Asymmetric Encryption with TLS to send the data to the cloud.

Obviously the largest part of security depends on how good you code all the system.

Comment: In general Asymmetric Encryption is not used to encrypt data but rather to encrypt keys. https uses TLS which in turn uses symmetric encryption to encrypt the data and asymmetric encryption to encrypt the symmetric key. Missing from the answer is how to protect the symmetric key: use the Keychain iOS, I don't know how to accomplish that on Android.

Comment: @Zaph Give a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html and here
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html

Comment: That seems to be for PKI keys, is there an interface for arbitrary text/data as appropriate for symmetric keys and passwords? Is access rate limited to prevent bruise force attacks?